# Accessing members in a vector of objects as vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I have a c++ class that is contained as a vector of objects in another class.

```
class Small
{

public:

   int a;
   int b;    
   int c;
};

class Big 
{
public:

   vector< Small > getSmallVec() const { return m_smallVec;}

private:

   vector< Small > m_smallVec;    
};
```

I'd like to be able to access the members of the Small class as a vector themselves. In other words, I'd like to have a function in Big like

```
vector<int> getSmallVec_a()
```

which would return a vector that contains each value of int Small::a in m_smallVec. The only way I can think of doing it would be to iterate over m_smallVec and copy to a vector of int. Is there a way to do this without copying?

Comment: What sort of operations do you intend to perform on the returned vector from `getSmallVec_a()`? Perhaps you could return your own class that mimicked `vector<int>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is how you expect to access data and performance is important, have you considered using parallel vectors? Instead of

```
  std::vector<Small>
```

In "Big" you actually maintain 3 vectors

```
  std::vector<int> aVec;
  std::vector<int> bVec;
  std::vector<int> cVec;
```

All elements at 0 correspond to the 0'th "Small", and you can easily seperate out all the as from the bs.

This comes a lot of annoying bookkeeping that you'd be have to be sure to get right and encapsulate well. Its not a more elegant solution, I usually dislike this kind of thing and would probably question in a code review, but it would probably give you the best performance for the operations you've described.

Comment: I could go with parallel vectors, but the majority of my code doesn't need parallel vectors. I can get almost everything I need with vector< Small >. What I'm looking to do is create a simple search function (e.g. given input int, find if an element in vector< Small > has member b that matches input), and don't want to have to create a new one function to search each member. Is there something I could do with templates and boost?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do that without seperating small components in diffrent vectors since a vector is just working as an array that means when you are creating a vector of smalls there will be 2 blocks space between small::a variables whereas what you what to return is just an array of ints. and by the way it's much more efficient if you delcere you function as `vector <int> & getSmall()` since if you don't return a refrence it'll cause a copying m_smallVec and returning it as the result, it also makes it impossible to change any value in m_smallVec.